# Использование Partial для класса формы

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Пытаюсь разделять код на файлы. Вот заголовок моего класса:

```
public class Form1 : Form
```

Во втором файле пишу:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

Всё работает, но в Solution Explorer этот файл отображается как форма (наверняка потому что подключена Windows.Forms). Я то хотел только код а тут такое, это нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это нормально: ведь всё это один и тот же класс.

Я рекомендую обратить внимание вот на что.

Если кода стало много и начинаете делить класс на несколько листингов через partial - то давно пора задумываться о рефакторинге и вынесении части бизнес-логики в отдельные классы.

И уже для новых классов выбирайте при вставке тип `Class`, а не `Windows Form`:

[image: Add new item]

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно сделать правильное отображение вашего дополнительного файла как файла с кодом.

После создания данного файла (я назвал его Form1Ext.cs) выполните построение проекта.

Выгрузите проект: правый клик мышкой на проекте в Solution Explorer > Unload Project.

Откройте любым текстовым редактором (можно Блокнотом) файл {ProjectName}.csproj, находящийся в папке вашего проекта. Найдите там строку

```
<Compile Include="Form1Ext.cs">
```

Конечно, ищите название своего файла.

Замените вложенный узел

```
<SubType>Form</SubType>
```

на узел

```
<DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
```

Сохраните файл *.csproj. Можно закрыть текстовый редактор.

Загрузите проект: ПКМ на проекте > Reload Project.

У меня получилось следующее отображение в Solution Explorer:

[image: вложенный файл кода формы]

Comment: Поставил плюс, потому что о таком способе тоже нужно знать, но всё же лучше в продакшн поменьше хаков выводить и больше внимания уделять чистоте кода.

Comment: @AK - да, я согласен, что подобный трюк лучше не использовать.

Answer (score 1):

А я бы сказал что не стоит класс формы делить на части.
Основная причина -- это визуальный редактор.
По своему (многолетнему) опыту могу сказать -- Visual Studio плохо переваривает такие вещи как разделение формы на части, и наследование тоже.
То что у вас в Solution Explorer показывается не так как хочется -- это ещё цветочки.
А вот когда вы не сможете (совсем) открыть редактор -- тогда всё, править только руками, что сильно повлияет на вашу производительность.

Поэтому рекомендации:

- Не использовать наследование на формах, не делить на partial классы
- Выделяйте функциональность относящуюся к вычислениям, доступу к данным в отдельные классы
- Выделяйте однотипные визуальные блоки в отдельные User Controls