# WinForms и Wpf Файлы вложенные в файл окна

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

Если вы посмотрите на файл формы или файл окна (winforms в WFP)
там вы можете увидеть, что файл содержит вложенные файлы.
Возможно ли сделать что-то подобное?
Например, пытаясь сделать это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Class.x => hmlfile .hml
```

Спасибо

Comment: Вы же на русскоязычной части сайта, задавайте вопросы на русском языке

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543515/184217

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2017#compile)